# I want to delete the author with its _id. While querying its not showing any error but deletion does not take place from the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise, graphql, graphql-js

Here I am using promised-mongo. While querying its working fine but the particular data doesnot gets deleted from database. Can anyone help me?

```
 const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Mutations",
    fields: {
      deleteDonor: {
      type: Donor,
      args: {
        _id: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: function(rootValue, args) {
        let donor = Object.assign({}, args);
        return donorsCollection.remove({_id:donor._id})
          .then(_ => donor);
      }
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: May be you can try `{_id: ObjectId(donor._id.toString())}` instead of using `{_id:donor._id}` ?